# metadata insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to insert metadata values in a temp table. what is the easites thing to do it?

I have values like 3390,3391,8978,9899,7677,9656,5463 about 30-40 of them. I want to insert them into a temp table. Do not want to query a table since that is a big table and using an IN operator is very low in performance.

IS this the best way?

```
INSERT INTO #Table
Select '3390'
UNION ALL
select '3391'
UNION ALL
select '8978'
```

Any other suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be bit easier this way;

```
Insert into #temp (field)
select number
from (values (123),(456),(678),...,(432)) as t(number)
```

Or search for a split function and do it like;

```
insert into #temp (field)
select item from dbo.split('123,456,789',',')
```

To create and insert at the same time, you could use 'Select Into' syntax.